# How to build/deploy a Node AWS RDS backend for React S3 app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up an app on AWS that ...

1. Deploys a react app to an S3 bucket
2. Deploys a node backend that interacts with an AWS RDS database
3. Connects the react app front end to the node backend to do CRUD operations

Doing part 1 is easy and there are plenty of tutorials. However, parts 2 and 3 seem totally foreign to me. I have found nothing that explains how to tie the front end to the database or how to tie the front end to the back end.

Do I need an API Gateway?

Does the node backend have to be hosted on an EC2 instance?
If so, how do I do this?

Where does cloudformation come into play?

Answer (score 0):

> I have found nothing that explains how to tie the front end to the
> database or how to tie the front end to the back end.

Frontend connects to the backend by making HTTP API calls (via `fetch` or a library like `axios`) to the URL associated with the backend server.

The backend would connect to the database via NodeJS database connections.

The frontend should never connect directly to the database.

> Do I need an API Gateway?

Using API Gateway is entirely optional.

> Does the node backend have to be hosted on an EC2 instance?

The Node backend needs to be deployed on a compute service that can run NodeJS code, such as AWS EC2, ECS, EKS, Lambda...

> If so, how do I do this?

This part of your question is so broad it is off-topic for this site. Given your level of experience I suggest looking at AWS Elastic Beanstalk for deploying your backend.

> Where does cloudformation come into play?

CloudFormation is a tool you use to define your AWS infrastructure as code, so instead of clicking around in the AWS UI to create everything, and then not being able to reproduce that reliably when you need to, everything is defined in template files that can be tracked in source control.

Where it "comes into play" is if you decide you want to use an Infrastructure as Code tool, you might use CloudFormation. It is entirely optional.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think that the confusing part is that there are so many aspects that are "optional" and I don't really understand why. Why do cloudFormation, beanstalk, API Gateway, etc exist if there is no need other than convenience? Can I alter an app not using these items to do so after launching?

Comment: This is like asking why car companies make more than one type of car. Or why more than one item is on the menu at a restaurant. There are multiple ways of doing things,  because there are different benefits/drawbacks to each method. If there was only one "clearly better than everything else in all scenarios" method of doing things, then none of those other things would have a reason to exist.

Comment: I didn't say "there is no need other than convivence". I just said using those things are optional.  API Gateway and CloudFormation for example both add beneficial things to your project. However they also add complexity, and right now you probably aren't in a position to handle that added complexity. Again, I suggest just looking at Elastic Beanstalk (or perhaps AWS Lightsail) as those are geared more toward people who don't have much experience managing all these different lower level services themselves.